# Unstable doctrine schema with phone_number type

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm having a very strange behavior with the doctrine `phone_number` type. Here is my Provider class:

```
class Provider {
    /**
     * @var PhoneNumber
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="phone", type="phone_number", nullable=true)
     * @Serializer\Expose()
     */
    private $phone;
}
```

Pretty simple. And then I had my migration:

```
$this->addSql('CREATE SEQUENCE provider_id_seq INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 START 1');
        $this->addSql('CREATE TABLE provider (id INT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, description TEXT DEFAULT NULL, phone VARCHAR(35) DEFAULT NULL, email VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, image_name VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, image_updated_at TIMESTAMP(0) WITHOUT TIME ZONE DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id))');
```

But after that I keep having these lines dumped when I run a `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql`:

```
ALTER TABLE provider ALTER phone TYPE VARCHAR(35);
ALTER TABLE provider ALTER phone DROP DEFAULT;
ALTER TABLE provider ALTER phone TYPE VARCHAR(35);
```

And even if I do a `schema:update` I will have them on the next run. I'm considering going back to annotate a string(35) and live with it, but I have my `User` entity that works perfectly fine with the same annotation, kinda weird.

Anyone had this situation before ?

Comment: Does doctrine:schema:validate say anything of interest after this migration?

Comment: [Mapping]  OK - The mapping files are correct.
[Database] FAIL - The database schema is not in sync with the current mapping file.

Comment: I guess it makes sense seeing the dump-sql, but still, nothing of interest

Comment: For someone experiencing this kind of issue : schema sync sometimes breaks if you do not specify the exact server version in config (doctrine / dbal / server_version).

Comment: You're right, I don't remember how I fixed it back then but Symfony is more or less forcing you to explicitly give the version number.